# How to use getJSON with SAS stored process?

Tags: json, sas

I just tried to fetch JSON data from a SAS stored process.
The STP is being executed, but what do I have to code in Javascript to get the result?

my Stored Process:

```
filename xjson temp;
proc json out=xjson PRETTY;
   export SASHELP.CLASS / NOSASTAGS;
run;
data _null_;
  infile xjson;
  input;
  file _webout;
  put _infile_;
run;
data APPLIB.TEST001;
  infile xjson;
  input;
  json = _infile_;
run;
filename xjson clear;
```

and here is what I tried in Javascript ($.postJSON ist a POST wrapper for $.getJSON) - the Webpage itself is also generated by a SAS stored process:

```
proc stream outfile=jscript mod resetdelim='_do';
BEGIN
  $.postJSON('https://myServer/blabla/do?_program=/what/ever/STP'
      , { _pgm : 'json' , _SESSIONID : "&_SESSIONID", callback : "?" }
      , function (data) {
  alert ('got it '+data.length);
});
;;;;
```

I can see that the program "json" is executed: json-string is written to APPLIB.TEST001.
There's no alert message, so I lack some knowledge to get the data passed back to my Webpage...

Any hints?

Comment: We (Boemska) have an open source HTML5 for SAS adapter which can help you here:  https://github.com/Boemska/h54s. Further setup notes:  https://www.rawsas.com/2015/12/building-web-apps-with-sas.  This requires a different approach to what you are taking now - but by placing your web files on the SAS web server you will find debugging becomes waaay easier..

Comment: thank you, I'll try. Is it also suitable for updating content in select boxes while user types in a search box (typeahead selection)?

Comment: if you wanted to use SAS for that there are a few things to consider.  1) fast response times (pooled stp server), 2) some frontend javascript code to submit your current value to SAS, say every 500 milliseconds or so, and 3) a SAS service to send the updated values.  If you only have a few hundred values, you could probably build it all client side and send the full list just once from SAS.